# Is Quicksand a default font on Windows machines?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using the font 'Quicksand' to design a website. This font was already installed on my Macbook, but does anyone know if this is also a default font on Windows machines? Or would it be safer to include it in my CSS files?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, it's not a default font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through comments and a few other resources I found that it is not a default font on Windows machines - therefore I will have to include the font in my CSS files.